# What is the right value to solve heap memory?

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am having memory problems by running a NetBeans project with 15000 lines of code and multiple arrays. I believe that increasing the heap size should help since NetBeans is having problems scanning the project and having "errors" when adding more code.

I am using a 64 bit computer with 8 GB on RAM. Should I use `-Xmx512m`, `-Xmx1024m`, or more?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) should cover how to set the startup parameters for NetBeans

If your problem is related to the the JVM heap being too small, the simple answer is that you must increase it until there's enough, and you don't have any problems.

-Xmx1024m or even -Xmx2048m should be little problem if you have 8GB ram - even if it sounds like a lot, you might as well make use of the memory you have.